# How to select the idiom to understand my voice recognition software C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice, voice-recognition

Well Hello guys im making right now a little ap for voice recognition, but now he is only understanding spanish, if i talk in english he puts random words on the textbox list, do you now how to make him understand english too, and how can i make him understand me a little bit clearly?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        recognizer.SpeechRecognized += recognizer_SpeechRecognized;
        recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    }

    void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words)
        {
            listBoxResult.Items.Add(word.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `SpeechRecognitionEngine(CultureInfo)` instance.

For example :

```
private SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-EN"));
```

Comment: Additional information: 'La invocación del constructor del tipo 'jarvisProject1.MainWindow' que coincide con las restricciones de enlace especificadas produjo una excepción.' (número de línea: '3'; posición de línea: '9'). if use ur method this is the error that i get

Comment: Could you please translate that in English. Also you should have en-EN culture installed on your machine. Otherwise it would throw exception.

Comment: OK :D i think thats it, and how can i install it

Comment: You should downlad additional language pack. Have a look at this:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224